# How can i know whether the user is deleting or writing

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi how can i know whether the user is deleting or writing with TextEditingController?

I just want to take action while writing ?

```
final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textEditingController.addListener(_textFieldChanging);
  }

_textFieldChanging() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a global variable that holds the current text

```
String _text = '';
```

Then you can compare them every time in the listener

```
void _textFieldChanging() {
  String newText = _textEditingController.text;
  if(newText.length > _text.length) {
    // The person is writing
  } else if(newText.length < _text.length) {
    // The person is deleting
  } else {
    // no change in length
  }
  setState(() {
    _text = newText;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the Listener for this task. You can do it using `onChanged`.

```
 int textLength = 0;
  String theChange='';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              theChange = textLength < value.length ? 'Adding':'deleteing';
              textLength = value.length;
              setState(() {

              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        Text(theChange)
      ],
    );
  }
```